# How to convert MySQL Keyword to normal column

Tags: mysql, database-design

We thought of upgrading MySQL to new version 5.5.16. While testing the scripts with the new version, I had found one column **Maxvalue** is a **Keyword** in latest version.

For this one, we need to change all the application where it is used.
Instead is there any way to make the keyword **Maxvalue** interpret as a **Normal column**, so that we will not have to change our application.

Maxvalue is just column name, it is not the maximum value.

And I am looking for some other option apart from backticks: `Maxvalue`.

Answer (score 3):

I can see these choices

- don't rename add backticks everywhere
- rename the column

Like this

```
`Maxvalue`
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of, but you can keep the column name as "Maxvalue" if you wish, but you must remember to always dereference it when running a SQL query as follows;

```
SELECT max(`Maxvalue`) AS max_value
FROM `table_name`
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers from Dave and gbn are pretty much the only way.

[You could set ANSI_QUOTES for the session's SQL MODE but you would have to derefernce using double quotes instead of the backquote](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) (the whole sentence is a link)